# Openstack Octavia lbaasv2 : cannot find lbaasv2 service plugin

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to use Octavia load balancer with openstack pike. I add the following to my etc/neutron.conf file

```
    service_plugins = router,lbaasv2
```

When I restart the neutron-server I see the following in the log:

```
    Error loading class by alias: NoMatches: No 'neutron.service_plugins' driver found, looking for 'lbaasv2'
```

I installed Octavia using pip install. That went without error. Do I need to install or configure anything else? Thanks in advance for any help.

Ranga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octavia is a separate service from Neutron, and if you want to add Neutron LBAAS, which can be used a proxy between Octavia and Neutron you need to install neutron-lbaas.

> pip install -c https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?stable/pike neutron-lbaas

Keep in mind that you don't actually need neutron-lbaas (lbaasv2) to use Octavia. If you use the openstack cli, it will go directly to Octavia, and completely bypass Neutron.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is confusing on that point because it says neutron-lbaas is obsolete and yet refers to neutron-lbaas specific configuration. I have another problem with Octavia-api regarding keystone authentication (I'll post separately).

Comment: From your comment, I assume it is not necessary to specify service_plugin=lbaasv2 in neutron.conf. Neutron is completely unaware of the existence of octavia?

Comment: Neutron does not have to be aware of Octavia, but it can act as a api proxy.